# use echo but do not print (too much content)

Tags: shell-script

**EDIT**
I have a piece of a code, which printed out expected info and hindered me debugging. Then I was wondering if there is a way to 'use echo but do not print' or there was something in my code. Below was my original question.

**Original question**

I know my request maybe weird since many people are worried about 'not printing' and I can't get an answer since all my search are spammed by that. Eg, I just want the following code to be executed quietly without print {another_thing}. I am using GNU bash, version 4.3.48, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

```
for sth in $(echo $another_thing |jq -r 'keys[]');do
    count=$(echo $another_thing |jq -r ".[\"${sth}\"].somekey |length")
    echo ${count}
done
```

I only want to see:

1 .

2 .

3 .

..
instead of .

some long string .

some long string .

1 .

some long string .

some long string .

2 .

...

example of another_thing:

```
{
    "test": {
        "domain": "abc.com",
        "regions": [{
            "geo": "\"CountryCode\":\"AA\"",
            "server": "1.2.33.4",
            "action": "proxy",
            "proxy": "as-test.abc.com"
        }, {
            "geo": "\"ContinentCode\":\"BB\"",
            "server": "1.2.3.4",
            "action": "proxy",
            "proxy": "test.abc.com"
        }]
    },
    "sample": {
        "domain": "bbb.com",
        "regions": [{
            "geo": "\"CountryCode\":\"AA\"",
            "server": "4.5.6.7",
            "action": "redirect",
            "redirect": "abc.com"
        }, {
            "geo": "\"ContinentCode\":\"BB\"",
            "server": "6.7.8.9",
            "action": "proxy",
            "proxy": "sample.bbb.com"
        }]
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to get the info region info under each element and then do other stuff. A more detailed version of code inside 'for' loop

```
index=0
count=$(echo $another_thing |jq -r ".[\"${sth}\"].regions |length")
while [ $index -lt $count ]; do
    geo=$(echo $another_thing |jq -r ".[\"${sth}\"].regions[${index}].geo")
    geoid=$(echo ${geo} |sed 's|"||g' |awk -F: '{print $2}' |tr [:upper:] [:lower:])
    server=$(echo $another_thing |jq -r ".[\"${sth}\"].regions[${index}].server")
    some_function ${varible_1} ${varible_2} $server $geo $geoid
    index=$(expr $index + 1)
done
```

Comment: I'm not sure what long string that would output apart from the lengths, at least unless you get any errors from `jq`. Can you add a sample of some data with the problem? (Just a small snippet is enough, it just needs to make the issue clear.)

Comment: @ilkkachu just added in the question, is it what you are looking for?

Comment: @Vlastimil did you mean the title? I just changed to lowercase

Comment: I'm unsure of what it is you are trying to do with the code.  You are passing a variable into `jq` insecurely.  Do you want to get the length of e.g. the `.domain` for each object?  You can get that with `jq -r '.[].domain|length'`.  Also, it's unclear what text it is you want to not display.

Comment: @Kusalananda I just updated my question.

Comment: @tikael  ,do check if `some_function` is doing some echos internally - that is the only source of any output seeping in , with the current information we have

Comment: @amisax I am pretty sure it is not, since I've tried comment out that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm honestly not quite sure where you get the output from that you say you're getting, but the shell code that you are using is overly complex, calling four external utilities in each iteration (apart from what `some_function` may be doing).

Here's an alternative implementation (assuming the JSON data is in `file.json`):

```
#!/bin/bash

jq -r '.[].regions[]|[.geo, .server]|@tsv' <file.json |
while IFS=$'\t' read geo server; do
    geoid=${geo#*:}
    geoid=${geoid//\"/}
    some_function "$variable1" "$variable2" "$server" "$geo" "$geoid"
done
```

For the given data, the `jq` call would generate the following output:

```
"CountryCode":"AA"      1.2.33.4
"ContinentCode":"BB"    1.2.3.4
"CountryCode":"AA"      4.5.6.7
"ContinentCode":"BB"    6.7.8.9
```

This is a tab-delimited text which the shell loop is then reading into `geo` and `server`.

The `geoid` is simply parsed out of `$geo` by first deleting the stuff before the `:` and then removing any double quotes from the remaining value.  This is done by using two variable substitutions (of which the second one needs a shell like `bash`).

The `some_function` is then called.

To debug your output issue, let us know what `some_function` does.

Comment: I guess I need to revise my code...thanks for pointing out my code is to complex.